# how to set date format as per given in php

Tags: php

I want to change the date formate with PHP and I want particular formate of date but it is not working.
I have tried the below code to change the date formate.

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
echo date_format($date,"dth M Y");
```

and I want date like 15th sep 2013 or 1st sep 2013.

can anybody help me with this.

Comment: `date_format($date,"jS M Y");` ? src to the format : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `S` format specifier for English Ordinal suffix:

```php
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
echo date_format($date,"jS M Y");
```

From [Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> `S`   English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters   st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j

Demo: https://3v4l.org/PoTt9